# Separate commented blocks - Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express

Tags: visual-c++

As MS Visual C++ users know, the program allows you to collapse comment blocks. But, unfortunately, it simply collapses ALL comments from the first one to the first non-commented text.  For example, given code that looks like this:
[image]
(where the first two blocks are commented-out code), an attempt to collapse the first block causes all three code blocks to disappear, including the title of the last, non-commented block. This is the result:
[image]
I want to have a `[+]` for each of the three blocks, or at least, to keep the `/*Rainbow for display range*/` title visible, while the rest is hidden.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express (added in title now), thank you for your comment.